Python - interface composition and traits
I have a case in which I have an interface (ABC), Property, and a property can have one or more property traits:
@dataclass
class Property(ABC):
    name: str


class TraitA(ABC):
    def do_a():
        pass

class TraitB(ABC):
    def do_b():
        pass

class TraitC(ABC):
    def do_c():
        pass

And, examples of implementations:
@dataclass
class StringProperty(Property, TraitA):
    def do_a():
        return "string_a"

@dataclass
class BoolProperty(Property, TraitA, TraitB):
    def do_a():
        return "bool_a"

    def do_b():
        return "bool_b"

@dataclass
class AnotherProperty(Property, TraitB, TraitC):
    def do_b():
        return "another_b"

    def do_c():
        return "another_c"

And lets say I have a list of properties, and I want to handle them based on their traits, but I also need to access the fields in Property (the name field)
So I can do something like this:
def handle_properties(properties: List[Property]):
    handle_trait_a_properties(filter_trait_a_properties(properties))
    ...

def filter_trait_a_properties(properties: List[Property) -> List[TraitA]:
    return [cast(property, TraitA) for property in properties]

def filter_trait_b_properties(properties: List[Property) -> List[TraitB]:
    ...

def filter_trait_c_properties(properties: List[Property) -> List[TraitC]:
    ...

def handle_trait_a_properties(properties: List[TraitA]):
    for x in properties:
        print(f"{x.name} {x.do_a()}")

def handle_trait_b_properties(properties: List[TraitB]):
    ...

def handle_trait_c_properties(properties: List[TraitB]):
    ...

The issue is that each trait doesnt have the name property.
The solution I found is to use Union[Property, TraitA] and then I can access both of the interface properties.
My question is - is there any other way to achieve this? Can I somehow create interfaces that can be used only by a class that implements the "Base" interface?
Thanks
